# ggplot2's facet grid label not in the right position when using switch option

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using facet_grid in the ggplot2 R package to display different groups of data, but for some reason, the facet labels and axis labels are switched in order relative to what the [ggplot2 documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html) shows. As an example, the code I'm using is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
data <- transform(mtcars,
              am = factor(am, levels = 0:1, c("Automatic", "Manual")),
              gear = factor(gear, levels = 3:5, labels = c("Three", "Four", "Five")))
p <- ggplot(data, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(am ~ gear, switch = "both")
```

which gives the plot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5dpi.jpg). Note that the facet labels are above and to the right of their respective axes labels, while the documentation shows otherwise. Any idea what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link to the documentation is for version 2.1.0. http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/facet_grid.html is the documentation for the current version 2.2.1 and the plot is the same as your plot.

Comment: The [NEWS](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md) for 2.2.0 mentions all this. For `facet_wrap` you can control what happens with `theme(strip.placement = "outside")`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I hadn't realized that the this was new to version 2.2.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to J_F and Axeman for helping me sort this out. This behavior is new to version 2.2 of ggplot2. To make the facet labels appear on the outside of the axes labels, use:

```
theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```